# We have a ranch home with baseboard heat, 2 zones work 2 zones dont

Tags: water-circulating-heating

We have 4 zones and 4 thermostats with baseboard heat in our ranch home.. 2 zones are working, and 2 zones are cold.  What would cause this?

Comment: Have you checked circuit breakers?   Keep in mind a tripped breaker is loose in the center position, they don’t click to the off position if tripped.  To reset a tripped breaker you must move it to the full off position, then back to on.

Comment: We need more information including the location of the non working zones, how are they piped, are the non-working zones higher than the working zones, how are the zones controlled, pumps or zone valves. There a lot of working and retired HVAC guys that monitor this site. We can't guess, we need more information and pictures if you can.

Comment: If it was a tripped circuit breaker, nothing should be working.

Comment: You gave us zero information to help troubleshoot your problem. What zones aren't working? Do you have zone valves or circulators? Has it just recently stopped working? If so, what has changed? Does the furnace respond with clicking when you turn up and down the thermostats?

Comment: Folks, the tag says water -circulating heat.  This is not electric heat.